# R shiny renderTable column name align center

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing R shiny, and I want to make the column name of the renderTable to be center-aligned.

I have tried this, but it only makes the table move to the center to the panel.

```
#UI
      column(12, align = "center", tableOutput("table_of_item")), (XXXWRONG!)
```

So

```
  output$table_of_item <- renderTable({ #the table in the middle
if (is.null(rv2$data_batch))return() #to check the file is imported 

t <- dataset_preprocess_batch(rv2$data_batch) #data preprocess

head(t,n=20) #show the data with the first 20 row only
})
```

table_of_item is one of the example, I want to make all the renderTable 's colname to be center-aligned.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
renderTable({
  yourTable
}, align = "ccc")
```

with as many `c` as there are columns in your table (i.e. one `c` for each column).

Comment: Is there possible to "ONLY" make the column name center align, but not the rest of the table?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point you to a very good R package to easily create (and modify) almost all parts of a table. It is called `gt`  . See: https://gt.rstudio.com/index.html
It can also be used with shiny via `output_gt()` and `render_gt()`

Here is some example-code that might work for your problem:

```
library(gt)
yourtable<-data.frame(col1=paste("Sample", letters[1:10]),col2=rnorm(10))

yourtable %>% 
  gt() %>%
  cols_label(
    col1="Sample Name",
    col2="Values"
  ) %>%
  cols_align(align = "center",
             columns = 2)
```

However the `cols_align()` function also aligns the whole column (not only its labels) as you asked in your comment... Not sure if this is possible at all. But maybe you can still use the package to create a nice table suitable to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information, unfortunately, I am only allowed aligns the column name.(from our client request :(  )

Comment: That's unfortunate. I am currently not aware of a "natural" solution, but the last resort (so to say) could be the introduction of blank spaces before and/or after the column name to just make it "look" like it is centered. Of course this is a very dirty solution and probably will look ugly if the end result is viewed on devices with different resolutions... Sorry I couldn't help better!

Comment: We finally communicated with our cilent that R just can not do it.

Comment: Still very big thanks for your help! :)